# Using Switch and JOptionPane

Tags: switch-statement, joptionpane

Problem: Ask the user to enter 0-9999 and convert it into words using switch case and JOptionPane...
My question: I figure out how to convert the other numbers but if I entered 11-19, the output for example I enter 11 - "Ten One" how can I get the right output for this?

Comment: Please provide more details. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NumbertoWords {​​
 
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {​​​​​​​​​
        // TODO code application logic here
        int num=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a Number from [0-9999]"));
        
        int thou=num/1000;
        int temp=num%1000;     // 9999
        int hun=temp/100;       //999  -> 9
        int temp1=temp%100;
        int tens=temp1/10;       //99 
        int ones=temp%10;
        
        String display="";
        
        
        switch(thou){​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
            
            case 9: display=" Nine Thousand"; break;
            case 8: display=" Eight Thousand"; break;
                  
        }​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
       
        switch (hun){​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
            
            case 9: display=display+ " Nine Hundred"; break;
            case 8: display=display+ " Eight Hundred"; break;
        }​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
        
        switch (tens){​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
            case 9: display=display+ " Ninety"; break;
        }​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
        
        switch (ones){​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
            case 9:  display=display+ " Nine"; break;
            
        }​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
        
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, display,"Number to Words",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
      System.exit(0);
    }​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
    
}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```